# WPF pack:/[assemblyName];component/... vs pack://application:,,,/[assemblyName];component/...?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I came across this oddity while trying to resolve issues using merged ResourceDictionaries in a WPF app I'm working on.

I have custom controls (TextButton, MenuButton) and resources (colors, brushes, control styles and custom control templates) defined in an external DLL ("common"). In another library I have a user control that uses these styles ("pluginA").

As long as I was working with the standard WPF controls (TextBlock, Button, Grid etc.) - I could apply the styles from the "common" dll without any problems. The designer would pick up the style and apply it correctly.

If I plop in one of the custom controls (TextButton) into the User Control in "pluginA" - the designer would find the *custom control*, but couldn't resolve the type for the style to be applied (Type reference cannot find the type named '{clr-namespace:Common}TextButton').

The xmlns declaration in my usercontrol looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PluginA.Views.LeftBarView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:core="clr-namespace:Common.Core;assembly=Common"
             xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common;assembly=Common"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <core:SharedResourceDictionary Source="/Common;component/Resources/DefaultTheme/DefaultTheme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

With this definition, the designer doesn't apply any styles - but it works in runtime. Great, but not quite that helpful as I don't want to run the application to see if a minor tweak took effect.

So I tried this:

```
<core:SharedResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Common;component/Resources/DefaultTheme/DefaultTheme.xaml" />
```

But that didn't change anything (designer still wouldn't find the resources). In the process of changing the code, I got to this:

```
<core:SharedResourceDictionary Source="pack:/Common;component/Resources/DefaultTheme/DefaultTheme.xaml" />
```

Now the designer is happy and can find the resources - runtime is happy and displays the resources, and yet I can't find any description of this being a valid PACK URI... Can anyone explain why this would work?

Comment: Did you try rebuilding when you have the **valid pack uri**?

Comment: Sorry - got pulled off onto other things. I'll give it a try tomorrow when I get to work.

Comment: I changed it back to a valid pack URI and it worked great. I did install Update 4 to VS2013 between then and now, maybe there was something that got fixed that caused it to work as expected again...? Thanks for your help!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `pack:/Common;component/Resources/DefaultTheme/DefaultTheme.xaml`

This is technically a valid URI, but it is not a valid `pack` URI.  Parsing it according to the rules of the `pack` format would yield:

Package URI: *`<empty>`*
Part URI: `/Common;component/Resources/DefaultTheme/DefaultTheme.xaml`

In effect, you have made an absolute URI out of a part URI by appending the `pack:` scheme.  However, without a well-formed package component, the result is not a valid `pack` URI.  And, interestingly, the `Uri` class will not actually parse the original string as an absolute URI; it is parsed **incorrectly** as a relative URI, and that is part of the reason it works when assigned to `ResourceDictionary.Source`.  Let's take a look at the property setter:

```cs
public Uri Source
{
    get { return _source; }
    set
    {
        // ...
        _source = value;

        Clear();

        Uri uri = BindUriHelper.GetResolvedUri(_baseUri, _source);
        WebRequest request = WpfWebRequestHelper.CreateRequest(uri);
        // ...
}
```

The key lies within `BindUriHelper.GetResolvedUri(_baseUri, _source)`.  The logic there, which differs from much of the `pack` URI handling in WPF, sees that `_source` is not an absolute URI (at least according to the broken `Uri` class), so it attempts to combine it with the resolved base URI, which we presume to be `pack://application:,,,/`.  The URIs are combined via `new Uri(Uri baseUri, Uri relativeUri)`, which works only because `Uri` incorrectly parsed the original string as a relative URI.  The URI which ultimately gets used to create the `WebRequest` is equivalent to:

```cs
new Uri(
    new Uri("pack://application:,,,/"),
    new Uri("pack:/Common;component/Resources/DefaultTheme/DefaultTheme.xaml"))
```

...which produces:

```
pack://application:,,,/Common;component/Resources/DefaultTheme/DefaultTheme.xaml
```

And viola, we end up loading the resources from a valid pack URI even though we gave it an invalid one.

We know that the "bad" URI works because it gets accidentally transformed into a good one.  As to why that same "good" URI not work in the designer when it's used directly, that is very curious.

Perhaps you simply need to rebuild both the `Common` project and the project that is attempting to merge the resource dictionary.  If it still fails, then it's possible your `UserControl.Resources` has a different `BaseUri` when running in the designer than it does at runtime.  Let's see if we can figure out what the `BaseUri` is at design time.  Modify your `UserControl` as follows:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             ...
             xmlns:m="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Markup;assembly=System.Xaml"
             x:Name="Root">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary">
      <Style x:Key="BaseUriTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Text"
                Value="{Binding ElementName=Root,
                                Path=Resources.(m:IUriContext.BaseUri)}" />
      </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BaseUriTextStyle}" />
</UserControl>
```

See what gets displayed in the designer.  It may give us a clue.